# Python create a thread and start it on key pressed

Tags: python, multithreading, math

I've made a python script that factorizes a number into its prime factors. However when dealing with big numbers i may like to have an idea to the progress of the computation. (I simplified the script)

```
import time, sys, threading

num = int(input("Input the number to factor: "))
factors = []

def check_progress():
    but = input("Press p: ")
    if but == "p":
        tot = int(num**(1/2))
        print("Step ", k, " of ", tot, " -- ", round(k*100/tot,5), "%", end="\r", sep="")


t = threading.Thread(target=check_progress) ?
t.daemon = True ?
t.start() ?

k = 1
while(k != int(num**(1/2))):
    k = (k+1)
    if num%k == 0:
        factors.append(int(k))
        num = num//k
        k = 1
print(factors)
```

I'm wondering if there is a way to show the progress on demand, for example, during the loop, i press a key and it prints the progress?

How can i implement a thread of something like that in my script?

Thanks and sorry for my english

Edit:

```
def check_progress():
    while True:
        but = input("## Press return to show progress ##")
        tot = int(num**(1/2))
        print("Step ", k, " of ", tot, " -- ", round(k*100/tot,5), "%", sep="")
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is one possible design:

Main thread:

- create [queue](https://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html) and thread
- start the progress thread
- wait user input

  - on input:
  - pop result from queue (may be `None`)
  - display it
  - loop

Progress thread:

- do the work an put status in queue

I can provide example, but I feel you are willing to learn. Feel free to comment for help.

Edit: Full example with queue.

```
from time import sleep
from Queue import Queue
from threading import Thread


# Main thread:
def main():
    # create queue and thread
    queue = Queue()
    thread = Thread(target=worker, args=(queue,))

    # start the progress thread
    thread.start()

    # wait user input
    while thread.isAlive():
        raw_input('--- Press any key to show status ---')

        # pop result from queue (may be None)
        status = queue.get_nowait()
        queue.task_done()

        # display it
        if status:
            print 'Progress: %s%%' % status
        else:
            print 'No status available'

# Progress thread:
def worker(queue):
    # do the work an put status in queue
    # Simulate long work ...
    for x in xrange(100):
        # put status in queue
        queue.put_nowait(x)
        sleep(.5)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Now i actually managed to make it kinda work modifying the script like show but i don't know if it's the proper way

Comment: You are using variables accross threads which is not advisable. Queue are made for sharing accross threads. I edit my answer with a thread safe example.